# What should I do if the rendering doesn't match the video?

Tags: hdri

I used an HDRI environment map, but even with it, the rendering doesn't fit into the "live" environment captured on video.  The image in the video is a little noisy, the black color is lighter, and the white color is darker. How can I fix this and bring the quality and colors of the rendered object closer to the quality and colors of the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edited because I misread the first part of the question]

To add noise to your render you can tray overlaying a noise texture over your rendered image in the compositor. Specific settings or animated values are hard to predict, but it's a start.

[image]

To adjust your blacks and whites you can try going to the Render properties tab and under Color Management you can enable "Use Curves", then you can add handles to the curve in the little graph to tweak your values (sliding the "ends" of the curve might be most useful for you in this case).

[image]

Comment: I don't think _Denoising_ will help when trying to match the render to the original noisy footage.

Comment: @Gordon ah yes, I misread that. Hm, maybe generating a noise texture and overlaying that on top of the render in the compositor?

Comment: The _Noise_ texture is a good idea. And actually it changes with every frame I think, not like e.g. _Clouds_, which needs to be animated in order not to look weird and static.